# Areas of Cellar Accessed by Butler

Tags: bedikas-chametz

I occasionally send my butler down to the wine cellar during a meal to fetch more wine. The cellar is arranged as a three-dimensional grid of wine barrels. Which rows and columns of the grid do I need to check for leavened food before Passover, to verify there's nothing that was left behind absent-mindedly by the butler?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%98

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: "Which rows…": Are the barrels on their sides or standing? If they're standing, then I assume you're asking only about how far into the cellar (front to back) and which columns (right to left) — but not which heights (top to bottom), since there's nowhere to place food except on the very top. Right? Or are they staggered like שירת האזינו?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [mishnaberura.com](http://www.mishnaberura.com/Default.asp?SeifDate=3/18/2006)

> Q: Must a person search for Chametz in his wine cellar in his home?
>
> A: If he (or his butler) occasionally goes there to bring wine to the
>   table, and it is therefore possible that some Chametz had been brought
>   there, he must search the top two layers of bottles in the first row
>   one encounters upon entering the cellar (Shulchan Aruch 433:9, Mishna
>   Berura 433:40).

Although the reference quoted uses the word "bottles", the [source](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.433.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) uses the word "חָבִיּוֹת" which means barrels.

> מַרְתֵּף שֶׁמְּסֻדָּרִין בּוֹ שׁוּרוֹת שֶׁל חָבִיּוֹת זוֹ אֵצֶל זוֹ
>   עַד שֶׁנִּתְמַלֵּא כֻּלּוֹ, וְחוֹזְרִין וּמְסַדְּרִין שׁוּרוֹת
>   אֲחֵרוֹת עַל הַתַּחְתּוֹנוֹת עַד הַקּוֹרָה, אֵין צָרִיךְ לִבְדֹּק
>   אֶלָּא שׁוּרָה הַעֶלְיוֹנָה וְאַחֶרֶת לְמַטָּה מִמֶּנָּה; דְּהַיְנוּ
>   שׁוּרָה עַל פְּנֵי רֹחַב הַמַּרְתֵּף, וְלֹא עַל כָּל שֶׁטַח
>   הַמַּרְתֵּף אֶלָּא עֶלְיוֹנָה הָרוֹאָה אֶת הַקּוֹרָה וְאֶת הַפֶּתַח,
>   וְאַחֶרֶת לְמַטָּה מִמֶּנָּה

.